# How to convert a list of unix dates to a readable format

Tags: python

I know how to convert unix date to a readable date but I'm having a hard time of converting an entire list of unix dates.

Here's my current code:

```
time = df['Time']
list(np.float_(time))
print(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(time/1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

And the output:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-6532ae588a4d> in <module>()
     45 time = df['Time']
     46 list(np.float_(time))
---> 47 print(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(time/1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
     48 
     49 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py in wrapper(self)
    110             return converter(self.iloc[0])
    111         raise TypeError("cannot convert the series to "
--> 112                         "{0}".format(str(converter)))
    113 
    114     return wrapper

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `list(np.float_(time))`?  You're creating a new list, but not saving it anywhere.

Comment: I figured it would convert the original list

Comment: i think problem is "np.float_(time)" why are you converting it into float ?

Comment: I did that because if I just delete that line have only                                            time = df['Time']

print(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(time/1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))                the same error pops up

Comment: @MikeKassel: You can't divide a `pandas` dataframe => `(time/1000)`

Answer (score 1):

If your pandas DataFrame already has a column of UNIX timestamp floats, directly convert it to timestamp strings using [pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'unix_ts': [140000000000, 15000000000]})
print(df)
print(pd.to_datetime(df.unix_ts))
```

```
        unix_ts
0  140000000000
1   15000000000
0   1970-01-01 00:02:20
1   1970-01-01 00:00:15
Name: unix_ts, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has built-in support for this kind of things:

```
time = pandas.to_datetime(df['Time'])
```

Depending on the format of `Time` column, you will need to specify the `format` parameter of `to_datetime`. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Afterwards, it is easy to convert that `time` serie (which contains `Datetime` objects) to a serie of strings, using `time.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
time = df['Time'].astype(float).tolist()
```